# How to download packages on Mac OS X to install to ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, mac

I have ubuntu 16.04 LTS and a mac. I would like to know how could I do to downloads packages on my mac with internet to transfer it to my ubuntu without internet at work. I need packagees like eclipse and git to be able to install them with no internet on my ubuntu computer. I have tried lots of programs like sushi huh or keryx through wine but even by updating packages list I can't find what I want.
Thanks for any help!
This is not a duplicate post because the how to download packages for offline use thread has no answers for mac users!

Answer (score 0):

---

Assume a 64bits Ubuntu 16.04 .

Examples 1) eclipse http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/eclipse : The red dots are the dependencies → eclipse-jdt, eclipse-pde → must also be downloaded and installed. Links to eclipse : http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/eclipse/download

2) git http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/git : Dependencies → libcurl3-gnutls, liberror-perl, libexpat1, libpcre3, perl-modules, patch, rsync, ssh-client .
Links to git, amd64 http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/git/download

The packages can be downloaded with any Internet browser, or with the `wget` command, if available.

Note : Be aware that the dependencies can also dependend on some packages, etc. etc. inter-dependencies. Please check.

Note 2 : Click the downloaded packages.deb , and they will be installed.

---